# Get a column from each Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server 2008

I have 2 tables and I want to get 2 columns from the 1st table and 1 column from the 2nd table

when I make JOIN it gives me another things...

here is my code:

```
Select SUM(Sales.CDnum) as CDnum, SUM(Sales.Total) as TotalMoney,
SUM(Expenses.Costs) as Expenses, SUM(Sales.Total - Expenses.Costs) as Winnings
from Sales
JOIN Expenses
ON Sales.ID = Expenses.ID
```

but when I execute the code it gives me only one raw from the 1st table and 1 raw from the second ... because I have 1 raw in the 2nd table and 1st I have many raws...

someone can help me....

Comment: give us example of data in both tables and expected result

Comment: I sell CDS and the 1st table it has 4 Columns: ID, Client, Quantity, TotalSell

The 2nd Table it has 3 columns: ID, ExpensesName, Cost

Comment: is sales.ID have the same meaning as Expense.ID ? why do you join on this column?

Comment: for example I sell 3 CDs for a client and total $15...and another client.....etc

Total of selling and total of CDs then Expenses are the cost of CDs 
Total selling - Total Costs then my winnings

Comment: first thing, is your join perform correctly? is salesID related with expensesid?

Comment: yes but I have the Sale.ID is more than the Expenses.ID

Comment: for example now I have 5 Sells and 1 Expense

Comment: I'm not sure that I made it right ... maybe it's wrong way to make it

Comment: do you want to calculate total sells and expenses or you want to divide them into several categories/groups/rows whatever you call it?

Comment: I want the sum of total sells and the sum of expenses then:
Totalsells - TotalExpenses = Winnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I see ID columns are not related to each other in both tables, so you need to union them, for example like in this query:

```
select sum(q.sales), sum(q.expense), sum(q.sales)-sum(q.expense) as winnings
from (
    select sum(Sales.Total) as sales, 0 as expense from Sales
        union all
    select 0 as sales, sum(Expenses.Costs) as expense from Expenses
) as q
```

Comment: sorry but what do you mean of sum(q.sales) what is "q"??

Comment: @DaveMas you need to get a better understanding of "union".  q is the new table created inbetween '(' and ')'

Comment: q is a alias for temporary table, try to remove it, as it really useless, of course remove q. prefixes for columns